# How to: migration many-to-many laravel artisan

Tags: php, laravel, migration, many-to-many, laravel-artisan

I am trying to find a way to migrate (and later on seed) a table generated by a  many-to-many relation in laravel 5.2 (using artisan).

I have both my User.php and Role.php model here. Also the migration I tried for the many-to-many table. [I can't work well with codeblocks here, so this is my code.](https://gist.github.com/NicolasVanhecke/6c65cb9d5976d83fa17f)

I get the error:

> General error: 1005 Can't create table 'connect.#sql-2d0_2e' (errno: 150) (SQL: alter table 'users_has_roles' add constraint users_has_roles_usersid_foreign foreign key ('usersId') references 'users' ('id'))

Comment: The link to code won't work anymore. It would be nice if you could provide it here.

Comment: I have had troubles with Github account on private and work, trying to merge stuff etc.. I am afraid I lost the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the problem is:

```
$table->bigInteger('usersId')->unsigned();
```

If you look into `users` table what type of column is for `id`. I think it is `integer` (unsigned) so it must be exact the same for column for which you create foreign key, so you should probably change above into:

```
$table->integer('usersId')->unsigned();
```

Comment: Oh god, that was part of the problem.. It must indeed be interger, not bigInteger. Also there was a constraint with some rollback issue not going according to plan. Anyway, it is fixed. Thanks